# Reverse for 'Project' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Project/(?P<id>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFAQJ.png)
[This the view of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjn2C.png)[This is the url of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2q8T.png)[This is the templates of my second view function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHa2.png)[This is the template of my first view function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2poZ.png)[This the model of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StNnp.png)

I tried to render the the data in my first view linked template but the second template data does not render in my page .
I want to render the data of my second template in my first template through url

Comment: Please edit your question and post text itself, not screenshots of text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct in `HTML`

put `{% url 'Project' project.id %}` insted of `{% url 'Project' Project.id %}`

```
{% for project in projects %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{project.id}}</td>
    <td>{{project.title}}</td>
    <td>{{project.vote_ratio}}</td>
    <td>{{project.created}}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'Project' project.id %}"></a></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

#### views.py

```
def Project(request,id):
    projectObj= project.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'user/single-project.html',{'projectObj':projectObj})
```

#### urls.py

```
path('Project/<uuid:id>/',views.Project,name='Project'),
```

Comment: even though I corrected the url from id to pk , I got the same error

Comment: still same error

Comment: the answer is updated check plz this time should be work.

Comment: Now I got this error: Reverse for 'Project' with arguments '(UUID('4885aa4c-afe5-4bc9-8549-0c0e22771371'),)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Project/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Comment: plz put code of model in question

Comment: I have already attached the models.py file code in my question

Comment: answer is updated check plz

Comment: welcome  enjoy coding